# How can I deduct (infer) coordinates of a pixel in the disparity map using the right or left image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to deduct coordinates of the pixel in the disparity image by using the coordinates of the same pixel in the right/left image.

For example: if Ar (Ar is a point in the right image) = (2,3), I want to deduct by using this coordinates that Ad (same point in the disparity image) Ad= (4,3)

I'm using OpenCV and c++.

Thank's a lot for helping and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Divide the image into 2 halves, flip one of them and take diff of both matrices, check for zero values.

Comment: Thank's for you're answer, can you please explain more. You're talking about the right image or the disparity map.

Comment: Can you attach an example in your question to make it more clear ?

Comment: if A is a point in the right image with coordinates A(2,3) I want deduct the coordinates of the same point in the disparity map by using the right image. I hope that is clear to you ?